# MutableLiveData does not get updated

Tags: android

I have a LiveData of pictures that get initialized with all the pictures in the database, I am trying to make it so when the user clicks on a subject, only the pictures related to that subject are displayed. 
But I still get all the pictures displayed.

My Code looks like this:

```
photoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this ).get(PhotoViewModel.class) ;
    photoViewModel.findPhoto(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_SUBJECT));
    photoViewModel.getAllPhotos().observe(this, new Observer<List<Photo>>() { (/* this initilizes the list*/

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Photo> photos) {
            photoAdapter.setPhotos(photos);
        }
    });
    photoViewModel.getSearchResults().observe(this, new Observer<List<Photo>>() { /*this should only give the related photos*/
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Photo> photos) {
            if (photos.size() > 0)
            {
                photoAdapter.setPhotos(photos);
            }
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show some more code, like where you're posting or setting the live data ( repository or viewModel ).

Comment: And it seems like you're setting the data to the same adapter, it is possible that one of the methods ( getSearchResults and getAllPhotos) is returning an empty list and is being set to recyclerView or listView. Check for that also.

Comment: I got it, I guess it was a conflict between the two observers or something. I removed the first observer and now it's working fine.